# Why allow a duplicate of a Main site question on Meta.Poker?

Tags: discussion

This meta is just a repeat of the question that got closed
[What the site isn't](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/what-the-site-isnt)

I tried to close as a duplicate of the original question but that is not allowed
The question needs to be on the same site to be a duplicate

What is the correct way to treat a meta that is just a  repeat of a poker.stackexchange.com question?

I don't think this belongs on meta and I was one of the votes to close the original question.

Comment: I dont understand what youre asking? or what you want to do? Are you trying to close this meta-question you've asked?

Comment: I clearly know how to close my own question.   The meta I linked is just a repeat of the original question.  In my opinion that is not the purpose of meta.

Comment: You haven't linked to a meta question, you've linked to a question on the main site.

Comment: @TobyBooth That would confuse the issue.  I will fix that or just delete my post.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster has asked in your linked meta question why his original question (on the main site) was closed. Its similar, but not the same. Some answers to the meta Q have given examples of good subjective/bad subjective distinctions which should be useful to the OP. I think its appropriate for the Meta site.

Comment: Agree they asked why as an addendum.  The majority is just a repeat.  Even your answer in my mind is more an answer to the original question.